# list of listening TcpListener on specific port

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

i have the following vb.net code

```
Dim serverSocket As TcpListener
serverSocket = New TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Port) port = 8080
```

i want to get the list of the any ***TcpListener*** listening to that port or any other port

i have two applications the first contain the above code and the second app contain `Dim clientSocket As TcpClient`

i want from the second app to detect any ***TcpListener***

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: Do you want a list of _any_ TcpListener, or just a list of _any_ TcpListener that was created by your application?

Comment: i edit my question , @VisualVincent

Comment: You could create a custom class storing a TcpListener variable/property. Then you could have a List or Dictionary and store each new listener class there. Example: `Dim Listeners As New List(Of MyListenerClass)` and `Listeners.Add(New MyListenerClass)`